# Permission denied - connect(2) when trying to establish a web connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

This issue is getting me crazy, especially as everything was working before.

Every time I try to establish a web connection, I end up with a Permission denied - connect(2) error, for example trying to launch bundler:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - connect(2) for "bundler.rubygems.org" port 443
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
```

Edit: to be clear the issue is not related to bundler, I get the same error message for the following code:

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get('google.com', '/index.html')
```

gives me:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': Permission denied - connect(2) for "food2fork.com" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)
```

Environment

```
    Bundler   1.11.2
    Rubygems  2.4.5.1
    Ruby      2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]
    GEM_HOME  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
    GEM_PATH  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0;C:/Users/user_name/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
    Git       2.7.2.windows.1
```

Comment: Could you have forbidden ruby from accessing the network? I'd have a poke through the windows security / firewall settings

Comment: Indeed a firewall issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"..everything was working before"  Before what? (may reveal the cause)

First check it's not an issue with windows Firewall.  Disable your firewall and try run `bundle install` again.

If that doesn't help, try changing the source line in your Gemfile to HTTP.  ie from

> source 'https://rubygems.org'

to

> source 'http://rubygems.org'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately same result with http
Not sure exactly what changed in my local environment, it was working a few days ago and I haven't done any change in Ruby installation since then, only a few changes on a App (whose previous version used to work but doesn't anymore).

Comment: hmm... @Fred, try `bundle install` with Windows firewall disabled.

Comment: Good one! I feel stupid not having tried it... It's indeed a firewall issue (Bitdefender auto-pilot blocked ruby.exe without a warning). Thanks a lot @Alxs!

Comment: Glad I could help @Fred, when you said you hadn't changed anything in your environment I figured it could be something sneaky Windows did on the quiet.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your `Gemfile`.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org' (remove s from https)
```

Then run the following command. Hopefully it will solve your problem.

```
bundle install
```

Also there is already a connection open. `connect(2)`. So Stop another connection. Run one connection at a time. In a same port 2 connection can't be open.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your help. There is no other connection I am aware of. I tried to restart the computer, nothing else is running but I still get this connect(2) error for both http and https ports. Any idea how I can identify this open connection?

Comment: I guess it through `connect(2)`. Are you using any ide?